# Timestamp intervals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp, faker

How can I pick a past date that is a Tuesday or Monday, then get timestamps at 2 week intervals in JavaScript? I am using faker.js. I can only get a date in the past in years, 2 and 1 as shown below.

`const releaseStart1 = new Date(faker.date.past(2, new Date(Date.now())));
 const releaseEnd1 = new Date(faker.date.past(1, new Date(Date.now())));`

Comment: What is the reason you would use faker for that?

Comment: Good point. It was the only way I knew of to get dates in the past. It would actually be better, if i could pick a Tuesday 3, 5, or however many months ago specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using moment as it will let you do something like

`let date = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format();`

Which will return the date. You can use `days` `weeks` `months` `seconds` `minutes` `hours` `etc`

https://momentjs.com/docs/